# How To Get Notes On Windows 10?

Tags: notes.app

I switched from my Mac to a PC that runs Windows 10 and have all my notes from the notes app on my Mac. How can I get all my notes? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can you perhaps [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/306531/edit) your question just to clarify what you mean by *get all my notes*? Are you just wanting to be able to view them? Do you want each of the notes editable within a particular Windows application? Something else?

Comment: I want to be able to perform all of the functions that the normal Notes App that came on my Mac was able to, so basically edit them and view them. Thanks for the warm welcome btw!

Answer (score 8):

If you mean the native Notes App, you can access your notes on [icloud.com](http://icloud.com), unless you don't have them backed up. Then you have to log in. If you have two-factor authentication turned on, you'll have to use another Apple device you own.

If you've successfully logged in, you now should be able to access your notes from the "Notes" app on the website.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your notes synced via iCloud then you can access them using a browser at [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com).

If your notes aren't synced via iCloud, then your options involve having to use your Mac to *move* them. Some options include:

- Use your Mac to sync the notes via iCloud, and then access iCloud from your PC to view/edit your notes, or to copy them into one of the apps on your PC.
- Use your Mac to copy/paste each of your notes into a separate file (e.g. using TextEdit or another text editor) and then saving them to a drive or an online service such as Dropbox and transferring/accessing them from your PC.
- Use your Mac to *share* each of your notes via email and email them to yourself for accessing via your PC and then copying/pasting them into WordPad or whatever app you want to use

Also, you may be interested to know that you can also install iCloud for Windows:

- [What is iCloud for Windows?](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204301)
- [Download iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204283)
- [Set up and use iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201391)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed iCloud for Windows on Surface Pro and even though all the apps show up listed in the Windows Explorer iCloud app, Notes launches a browser with icloud.com in the address. It seems we aren't there yet for having a native running app for Notes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: There is no windows native app for Mac OS Notes. You can only access them through a browser into iCloud. iCloud for Windows is intended to give you easy access to your iCloud files through Windows Explorer, but not to run Mac OS apps.